# ClassNotFoundException Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc

This is for an assignment for university.
Developing an application on IntelliJ and it requires a connection to a mysql database. I get a ClassNotFoundException on `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` Tried some googling around the issue and have added the .jar file to a lib folder in the module and have added the jar file to Project Structure -> Libraries;

[image: See image].

This seemed to fix other peoples issues. Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: if you use gradle or maven you should add dependency,mysql connection or add jar mysql driver to project

Comment: Please check that mysql jar is included to classpath. Full classpath is shown in run console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was something different, I had set up the driver fine(changed it to come from Maven which is much easier). I didn't know about checked and unchecked exceptions and that you have to include try catches to get the code to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten to add this library into your modules? Adding to the `lib` folder under that module is not a really way to finish that. See the "Dependencies" detail in "Modules" for more information.

And, using a Maven dependency is better than directly put a `.jar` file: Choose "From Maven" instead of "From JAR file" after clicked that plus button, then search for "mysql-connector-java", and choose the version you want. After that dependency was downloaded, it will ask you which module to add this library.

Comment: I've changed the dependency to Maven and the file is in "Dependencies". I think the issue is something completely different due to my lack of experience with Java and IntelliJ. Do you need try catch blocks to stop the IDE highlighting the exception and stop the module from building? I come from a c# visual studio background where they're not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Try to open a Project Structure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>), then open the Modules section and check the Dependencies tab. Your library should be present there.

[image: screenshot for detail].